How do you use gsap globally in a Nuxt 3 app?
I have some problem getting GSAP to work globally in my Nuxt 3 app. I'm using the imports in my "nuxt.config.ts" that looks like this:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { 
    enabled: true 
  },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  imports: {
    dirs: ['utils'],
  }
})

My directory structure is the same as described here: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/app
In my "/utils/index.js" i got:
export { gsap, ScrollTrigger, SplitText } from 'gsap/all'

I can then access all the stuff from files used in the "composables" folder like usual, without importing. gsap.to() etc, but when i try in for lets say "/pages/index.vue" it gets undefined.
What am i missing here?

Or... is the idea that one should use composables just for this? Like i can create one for certain gsap-animations and just do "useMyComposable()" whereever i need it.

Ok, found a good solution that i implemented: https://blog.bogdankostyuk.xyz/p/how-to-nuxt3-and-gsap/

Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it if it solves your issue.
But yeah, the main thing is to load it onMounted, the rest should not be too different IMO.
